# I this a correct way to send request to whisper api via Ajax

Tags: ajax, openai-whisper

I am getting back a 400 code
what I have to change in order to fix this issue
help....
function sendAudio(chunks){

```
         let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm; codecs=opus" });
         let formData = new FormData();
         formData.append("audio", blob, "recording.webm");

         let apiKey = ""; 
         let url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/wav2vec-2.0/transcribe";

         let header = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
         };
         $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: header,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(response) {
               console.log("Transcription:", response.text);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.error("Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
           }
        });
     }
```